# How to rewrite if directory OR sub-directory requested

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite

`mydir/xxx` to `mydir/fileA.php?param=xxx`

and

`mydir/xxx/yyy` to `mydir/fileB.php?param=yyy`

**`xxx` and `yyy` are wildcards.**

I've tried

```
RewriteRule ^mydir/(.*)/(.*)$       mydir/fileA.php?param=$2
RewriteRule ^mydir/(.*)$            mydir/fileB.php?param=$1
```

but I get a 500 misconfiguration error.

Comment: Rules don't appear to be related to requirement. How is `/xxx` related to `/home`? Can you clarify about requirements a bit more.

Comment: `/home` can be `/`, it doesn't matter, I just used it as an example.

Comment: Question is unclear to me.

Comment: Re-worded it to help explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules for this in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip real files and directories from more rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^mydir/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ mydir/fileA.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mydir/([^/]+)/?$       mydir/fileB.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can I place this in my root `.htaccess` instead of `/mydir/`?